# incorrect data input in file from an OutputStream( Java )

Tags: java

I wrote a data to text file, but data in file are incorrect. I think it is problem with OutpubStream, because I display data on previous steps, and they were correct.

```
private void Output(File file2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    OutputStream os;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(file2); //file2-it is my output file, all normal with him
        Iterator<Integer> e=mass.iterator();
        int r=0;
        while(e.hasNext()){
            r=e.next(); 
            System.out.println(r);//display data-all be correct
        os.write(r);//I think problem create in this step/
        }
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Input data file1.txt

```
10
56
2
33
45
21
15
68
54
85
```

Output data file2.txt

```
3 strahge tokens plus !-68DU
```

thanks for answers, excuse me for my english.

Comment: I read your question about 3 times and I still wonder what's the desired output

Comment: Could it be a Byte Order Mark?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you could consider transforming the string into a bytecode:

```
System.out.println(r);// display data-all be correct
String line = (String.valueOf(r) + "\n");
os.write(line.getBytes());
```

Comment: I think that the intented ouput 
10
56
...
So, why not transform the data into string, and then write the bytes out of it

Comment: Thank you, it is close to true. In this example I want use Java internal methods only.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
os.write(r);
```

Writes the binary value of integer r to the file.

Use something like:

```
os.write(String.valueOf(r));
```

and you probably want new lines:

```
os.write(String.valueOf(r)+"\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

[`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) is used to write binary raw Data. As specified in document :

> FileOutputStream is meant for writing streams of raw bytes such as
>   image data. For writing streams of characters, consider using
>   FileWrite

Since you are writing integers to the file so what you need is text-output Stream like [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html). It can be used in your code as follows:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file2); //file2-it is my output file, all normal with it
Iterator<Integer> e=mass.iterator();
int r=0;
while(e.hasNext()){
   r=e.next(); 
   pw.print(r);
   pw.println();//for new line
}
pw.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

use FileWriter instead of FileOutputStream as your data is text and you probably want to use a stream of characters